# Installing mongoimport in a docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoimport

from my node scripts I need to execute `mongoimport` via the `exec` function from `child_process`. When it comes to the CI tests in the docker image I run into a problem:

`/bin/sh: 1: mongoimport: not found`

Now I inserted the installation of mongodb in the drone.yml file:

```
- apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
- echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.2 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -d -y mongodb-org-tools
```

But still mongoimport isn't found. I even added the root `/` to the PATH variable or made a

```
find / -name "mongoimport"
```

Nothing.

Has anyone an idea, how to get mongoimport working in the docker image?

Thank you.

PS.: Here's the output from apt-get:

```
$ apt-get install -d -y mongodb-org-tools
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 102 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 135 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian/ jessie/mongodb-org/3.2/main mongodb-org-tools amd64 3.2.14 [31.4 MB]
Fetched 31.4 MB in 1s (28.2 MB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode
```

Comment: What is the Docker image you are using here?

Comment: `image: node:latest`

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I tried to install the wrong package.

```
- apt-get install -d -y mongodb-org-tools
```

It must be

```
- apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Then automatically the mongodb-org-tools are installed together with some other packages. Now mongoimport can be used

```
$ find / -name "mongoimport" -ls > out.txt
$ cat out.txt
 2038 10588 -rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root     10839312 Jun 13 22:30 /usr/bin/mongoimport
```